# What is the probability that the product of two randomly selected distinct positive integers less than $100$ is a multiple of $3$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two different positive integers less than $100$ are randomly chosen and multiplied together. What is the probability that the resulting product is a multiple of $3$?

Sorry about that. I used a different approach and got the answer. The answer is down Below.

Answer (score 2):

We can choose two numbers in $\binom{99}{2}=4851$ ways. Two numbers will have a product which is a multiple of 3 if at least one of them is a multiple of 3. We can more easily count the number of ways for the product to not be a multiple of 3: this happens when neither of the numbers is a multiple of 3. There are $\frac{99}{3}=33$ multiples of 3 less than 100, and $99-33=66$ numbers which aren't multiples of 3. The number of ways to choose two of these numbers is $\binom{66}{2}=2145$, so the number of way to choose two numbers where at least one is a multiple of 3 is $4851-2145=2706$. The final probability is $\frac{2706}{4851}=\boxed{\frac{82}{147}}$.

Comment: This looks fine.  As a slightly different approach, note that the probability that the first choice is not a multiple of $3$ is $\frac {66}{99}$ and, given that, the probability that the second is also not a multiple of $3$ is $\frac {65}{98}$, so the answer is $1-\frac {66}{99}\times \frac {65}{98}=\frac {82}{147}$, confirming your result.

Comment: Oh! Thank you lulu for telling me a different approach!